# Dual boot - Windows 10, Ubuntu 14.04. Hang on shutdown

Tags: shutdown

In this closed thread [link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1296782&) the issue was also addressed some time ago.

During the shutdown, the system seems to hang. 
I didn't try `alt-sysrq` options yet, but when 5 sec pressing power button on notebook, I hear that
nasty HDD sound when the heads didn't park correctly.

Currently, I have windows 10 as the main system, and Ubuntu 14.04 installed
on one of the partitions, accessible via bios boot override. The said partition
was chosen as `ext4` journaling. No swap.
The two OSs were independently installed.

I have already disabled the 'fast startup' windows option.

I wonder if windows doesn't like the existence of an `ext4` partition,
or Ubuntu doesn't feel comfortable being installed beside `ntfs` partitions.

Thing is, I'm positive this is no hardware issue, but I don't have the slightest clue
about the cause(s) and how this could be addressed. Nvidia drivers maybe. At the moment I'm less than
thrilled on using this Ubuntu installation as it is, for the risk of losing the HDD seems pretty real.

I could provide any additional system info, should someone need it.

Any help appreciated, thank you guys.

Per request, adding hardware info:

```
Motherboard: Notebook N85_N87HCHN
Chipset: Intel HM175 (Skylake PCH-H)
CPU: Intel Core i7-7700HQ
GPU onboard: Intel HD Graphics 610 (Kaby Lake-H GT2) - Integrated Graphics Controller [CLEVO/KAPOK COMPUTER]
GPU dedicated: Nvidia GTX 950M
OS (UEFI boot): Microsoft Windows 10 Professional (x64) Build 16299.125
BIOS date: 12/12/2016

Disks info:

Crucial_CT275MX300SSD4
Drive Controller:                       Serial ATA 6Gb/s @ 6Gb/s
Drive Model:                            Crucial_CT275MX300SSD4
Drive Capacity:                         262,321 MBytes (275 GB)
Media Rotation Rate:                    SSD Drive (Non-rotating)
 [Self-Monitoring, Analysis and Reporting Technology (S.M.A.R.T.)]
  [01] Raw Read Error Rate:               100/Always OK, Worst: 100
  [05] Reallocated Sector Count:          100/10, Worst: 100
  [09] Power-On Hours/Cycle Count:        100/Always OK, Worst: 100 (56 hours / 2.3 days)
  [0C] Power Cycle Count:                 100/Always OK, Worst: 100 (Data = 260,0)
  [AB] Program Fail Count (Total):        100/Always OK, Worst: 100
  [AC] Erase Fail Count (Total):          100/Always OK, Worst: 100
  [AD] Wear Leveling Count/Erase Count:   100/Always OK, Worst: 100 (Data = 9,0)
  [AE] Unexpected Power Loss Count:       100/Always OK, Worst: 100 (Data = 16,0)
  [B7] SATA Interface Downshift / Runtime Bad Block: 100/Always OK, Worst: 100
  [B8] Reported I/O Error Detection Code Errors: 100/Always OK, Worst: 100
  [BB] Uncorrectable Error Count:         100/Always OK, Worst: 100
  [C2] Temperature                        67/Always OK, Worst: 36 (33.0 °C)
  [C4] Reallocation Event Count:          100/Always OK, Worst: 100
  [C5] Current Pending Sector Count:      100/Always OK, Worst: 100
  [C6] Off-Line Uncorrectable Sector Count: 100/Always OK, Worst: 100
  [C7] SATA R-Errors (CRC) Error Count:   100/Always OK, Worst: 100
  [CA] Percentage Of The Rated Lifetime Used: 100/1, Worst: 100
  [CE] Flying Height:                     100/Always OK, Worst: 100
  [F6] Total Host Sector Writes:          100/Always OK, Worst: 100 (Data = 2262562291,0)
  [F7] Host Program Page Count:           100/Always OK, Worst: 100 (Data = 71081160,0)
  [F8] Background/FTL Program Page Count: 100/Always OK, Worst: 100 (Data = 40812784,0)
  [B4] Unused Reserved Block Count (Total): 0/Always OK, Worst: 0 (Data = 1236,0)
  [D2] SATA CRC Error Count:              100/Always OK, Worst: 100
  Drive Remaining Life                    100%
Number of Hardware Resets:              458
  Number of ASR Events:                   18
  Number of Interface CRC Errors:         0
  Used Endurance Indicator:               0%

ST2000LM015-2E8174

Drive Controller:                       Serial ATA 6Gb/s @ 6Gb/s
Drive Model:                            Seagate ST2000LM015-2E8174
Drive Capacity:                         1,907,729 MBytes (2000 GB)
Media Rotation Rate:                    5400 RPM
[Self-Monitoring, Analysis and Reporting Technology (S.M.A.R.T.)]
  [01] Raw Read Error Rate:               82/6, Worst: 64 (Data = 148846921,0)
  [03] Spin Up Time:                      99/Always OK, Worst: 99
  [04] Start/Stop Count:                  100/20, Worst: 100 (Data = 285,0)
  [05] Reallocated Sector Count:          100/36, Worst: 100
  [07] Seek Error Rate:                   64/45, Worst: 60 (Data = 2601596,0)
  [09] Power-On Hours/Cycle Count:        99/Always OK, Worst: 99 (948 hours / 39.5 days)
  [0A] Spin Retry Count:                  100/97, Worst: 100
  [0C] Power Cycle Count:                 100/20, Worst: 100 (Data = 259,0)
  [B8] End to End Error Detection Count:  100/99, Worst: 100
  [BB] Reported Uncorrectable Errors:     100/Always OK, Worst: 100
  [BC] Command Timeout Count:             100/Always OK, Worst: 100
  [BD] High Fly Writes                    100/Always OK, Worst: 100
  [BE] Airflow Temperature / Exceed Count: 77/40, Worst: 51 (23.0 °C)
  [BF] G-Sense Error Rate:                100/Always OK, Worst: 100 (Data = 1,0)
  [C0] Power-Off Retract Count:           100/Always OK, Worst: 100 (Data = 5,0)
  [C1] Load/Unload Cycle Count:           98/Always OK, Worst: 98 (Data = 4915,0)
  [C2] Temperature                        23/Always OK, Worst: 49 (23.0 °C)
  [C5] Current Pending Sector Count:      100/Always OK, Worst: 100
  [C6] Off-Line Uncorrectable Sector Count: 100/Always OK, Worst: 100
  [C7] UltraDMA/SATA CRC Error Rate:      200/Always OK, Worst: 200
  [F0] Head Flying Hours:                 100/Always OK, Worst: 253 (Data = 399,25036)
  [F1] Lifetime Writes from Host (LBAs Written): 100/Always OK, Worst: 253 (Data = 1750875602,0)
  [F2] Lifetime Reads from Host (LBAs Read): 100/Always OK, Worst: 253 (Data = 351298878,0)
  [FE] Free Fall Protection:              100/Always OK, Worst: 100
Number of Reallocated Logical Sectors:  0
  Read Recovery Attempts:                 0
  Number of Mechanical Start Failures:    0
  Number of Reallocation Candidate Logical Sectors: 0
  Number of Reported Uncorrectable Errors: 0
  Resets Between Command Acceptance and Completion: 0

deborphan:
libmpdec2
libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-xenial
libmpdec2
Reverse Depends:
  libmpdec2:i386
  libmpdec2:i386
  libpython3.4-stdlib
  libpython3.4-dbg
  libmpdec-dev
libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-xenial
Reverse Depends:
  libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-xenial:i386
  libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-xenial:i386
  libegl1-mesa-dev-lts-xenial
  libegl1-mesa-dev
apt-cache policy: both packages installed
```

Nvidia driver:
Software and updates, additional drivers:

Was: using x.org x server - nouveau display driver

Now: using nvidia binary driver - version 384.111

During shutdown process, no fail condition was found.
Nonetheless, system did not shutdown, and CPU speed started to raise up.

`Alt-sysrq` b was effective, and the system rebooted immediately.

After installing Nvidia driver and 1st time force restarting, 
everything worked ok afterwards.
Tried restarting and shutting down a couple of times, very fast
with no issues.
I decided to take a leap of faith and install a very demanding software,
to take things to the edge. After installing Pingus, everything still
worked fine.
If Michael wishes to change his comment about Nvidia driver into
an answer, I'll select it.
If no input happens in two days, I'll submit myself the said answer,
for completion sake.

Thanks Karel for the reply and thank you all very much for all the input.

Comment: what hardware do you have? which driver are you using for nVidia? When shutting down press the esc key, to see where it hangs at.

Comment: Ubuntu not shutting down properly can have multiple causes and yes, not having the proper Nvidia proprietary drivers is one of them. Having installed Ubuntu in Legacy mode when it should have been in UEFI mode like the factory installed Windows 10 certainly doesn't help but is unlikely to be the cause. Your hypotheses about dual boot are quite nosensical and so is the fear about the HDD, "head parking" is a thing of the 80s. You need a serious update.

Comment: @ravery Of course. The need to do that manually (via command) is what I meant by "a thing of the 80s"...

Comment: @MichaelBay -- OP was speaking of the audible click you hear on power loss as the heads rapidly return to the ramps. The sound is disconcerning though I'm not sure it it could actually cause damage.

Comment: @ravery It isn't a cause for concern in any drive manufactured in the last 20 years or so. But better avoid it by having the OS shutting down properly. The problem here is most likely the lack of Nvidia drivers though. My initial comment was intended only to dispel myths an nonsense so the OP can focus on an actual solution and on improving their knowledge, i.e., bring it to the 21st century ;)

Comment: Not sure if I implied I was parking drives manually, but that's not the case. My concern is that the Ubuntu shutdown process is not correct, and what happens with the HDD when I need to force power down if far from usual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the problem has been resolved, I'm posting the answer for future reference.

Systems
Windows 10
Ubuntu 14.04
OS switch via bios boot override

Symptoms:
. notebook starts process but can't shutdown/restart
. 5sec press power button turns system off, but HDD emits a loud sound,
like if heads did not correctly park

Solution:
. install Ubuntu Nvidia drivers

Thanks Karel for the reply and thank you all very much for all the input.

Answer (score 1):

The mechanical functioning of a hard drive does not depend on the software that is installed on it. The *smartmontools* package contains two utility programs (smartctl and smartd) to control and monitor storage systems using the Self-Monitoring, Analysis and Reporting Technology System (S.M.A.R.T.) built into most modern ATA and SCSI hard disks. This works because all modern disks log their health status using S.M.A.R.T. Use the following command to show this status:

```
sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdX
```

where **`X`** is replaced by the letter of the hard drive which can be found by selecting the hard drive in the Disks application and then finding it to the right of where it says *Device*. The *SMART overall-health self-assessment test result* reports whether the disk passed or failed, and other results of `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sd` provide more detailed information about the disk's health.

To install smartmontools in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install smartmontools
```

According to the latest edit of the question, the hard disk turned out to be OK, and the problem was caused by a software issue, not a hardware issue.